# How to load variables from a powershell script and access the same in groovy jenkinsfile pipeline variable

Tags: powershell, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a requirement where I have to load powershell variables from a powershell script and store the vairable value in a groovy jenkins pipeline variable and use it thereafter to edit the name of an artifact depending on that variable's value.

powershell script: Variables.ps1 (in real scenario this has number of variables but this is just for sample)

```
$Version = "22.4"
```

jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage('TestPowershell') {
      steps {
        script {
            def path = "${env.WORKSPACE}\\Power\\Variables.ps1"
            echo path
            def versionFromPowershell = powershell(returnStdout: true, script: " . '${path}'; return $Version;")
            echo versionFromPowershell
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get an error when I use this method as below:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Version for class: groovy.lang.Binding
at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:251)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:353)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:357)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:333)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:333)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:333)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:26)
```

In the vannila powershell the script works fine and does the job, not sure why the same syntax doesn't work when invoked via jenkins build. Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks

Shobhit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot interpolate Powershell variables in a Groovy interpreter. Therefore, the `script` argument to the step method must contain escaped variable syntax characters such that the variable `Version` is interpreted by Powershell and not Groovy:

```
def versionFromPowershell = powershell(returnStdout: true, script: " . '${path}'; \$Version;")
```

Comment: Thanks for that as I do not really do PS.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution worked great for me. There is a lot of confusion when i read documentation of groovy vs jenkinsfile groovy. There are lot of edge cases like this one.